# STM32G4 USB Link Power Management

Tags: usb, stm32

I want to use the USB 2.0 Port on an STM32G431CB as Virtual Com Port (VCP). The Device is self powered, so I need to enable the USB Link Power Management, to detect when the USB Cable is plugged in. The STM32G431 has no dedicated VBUS Pin, so according to this document [1] any 5 Volt tolerant pin with EXTI capabilities should be able to fullfill that role.

So far so good, but how do I reset the USB statemachine, when I detect, that the USB Power has been connected / the USB cable has been plugged in? I looked through several documents, but I could not find any hint, how I caould reset the USB Statemachine, when this Interrupt occurs. Is there any HAL function or something similar?

But it's even more confusing, that I can enable the Link Power Management in CubeMX, but there are no further parameters, like which Pin I'd like to use, or callback functions, etc. It's just an "enabled" or "disabled" - even the tooltip / online help is empty.

can anyone point me in the right direction?

[1] Link: https://community.st.com/s/article/FAQ-Management-of-VBUS-sensing-for-USB-device-design